# How does WebSolr support queries without q parameter

Tags: solr, websolr

When I submit a solr query without a `q` parameter I get Null pointer exception

```
# This works
http://localhost:8991/solr/select?q=hello

# This throws Null pointer exception
http://localhost:8991/solr/select
```

But when I use a WebSolr, the queries without `q` parameter returns all documents ( I am assuming q is assigned to `*:*`). Is there a solr configuration that enables this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
<requestHandler name="standard" class="solr.StandardRequestHandler" default="true">
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="q">*:*</str>
  </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

Comment: I tried this solution and I still get Null pointer exceptoion.

Comment: in the above code, try changing the first line to the following :-

<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">

Read somewhere that "standard" is legacy/deprecated

Comment: To be more clear, that requestHandler should go in your solrconfig.xml